# How to encode the password for an arbitrary entity in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I'm creating organizations table in mysql.

The entity is called `Organisation` and it has a `password` field.

When I try to use `UserPasswordEncoderInterface` it expects the `user` entity, so this doesn't work. I tried using `PasswordEncoderInterface`, but it says that the service is not exist. What can be done here ?

This is my code:

```
   public function register(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, PasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $organisation = new Organisation();

        $form = $this->createForm(OrganisationRegisterType::class, $organisation);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $plainPassword = $form->getData()->getPassword();
            $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword, null);
            $organisation->setPassword($encoded);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($organisation);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Organizacija sukurta sėkmingai. Nurodytu el. paštu buvo išsiųsta prisijungimo informacija'
            );
        }
```

This is the error I get:

> Cannot autowire argument $encoder of "App\Controller\OrganisationController::register()": it references interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PasswordEncoderInterface` does not exist.

The simplest solution would be to make your `Organisation` class implement the `UserInterface`.

The `UserPasswordEncoder` does not expect a `User` object, but an object that implements that interface. Even if your organization class is not a "user" per-se, it looks like you want it to have the same interface (username, password...).

Just change your organization class to implement that interface, and inject the `UserPasswordEncoderInterface` as usual.

Answer (score -1):

If the proposoal by @yivi is not applicable for your entity class, you can manually inject the respective encoder implementation to your controller. Either access the container in the controller, or even better [configure your controllers as services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html) and inject the service via [setter injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection).